# Handling print as PDF in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, autoit

I am trying to print as pdf by selenium but without the header and footer information. I made this code using Java and AutoIT tool to deal with the print window.

Here's my Java code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--kiosk-printing");
options.addArguments("--printing.paper_size_default");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("http://google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(10000);

//get page title tag so I can use later to put name on PDF file
String pageText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

//saving title text to clipboard so I can get on autoIT executable
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(pageText);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

//open print window and execute autoIT file
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("print()");
Thread.sleep(5000);

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("src/savfiles.exe");
```

Here's my autoIT code (savfiles.exe):

```
//getting title text that I copy to clipboard
Global $sLastClip = ClipGet();

//focus on name file
ControlFocus("Salvar Saída de Impressão como", "", "ComboBox1");
Sleep(500);

//past the text on field`
ControlSetText("Salvar Saída de Impressão como", "", "Edit1", $sLastClip);
Sleep(500);

//click on confirm button and save`
ControlClick("Salvar Saída de Impressão como", "", "Button2");
Sleep(500);

//if there's another file with the same name the operational system will ask if you want to replace the file. this line will confirm that yes
ControlClick("Confirmar Salvar como", "", "Button1");
```

I tried to put some prefs as ("isHeaderAndFooter", false) but it seems not working and I looked many documentations as I could and found nothing dealing with it (at least with java).

Comment: Not worked either